# Getting a concrete event from WP7 calendar

Tags: windows-phone-7, calendar

I'm working on a WP7 application and I need it to play the song in the first link if the current event on the calendar is "Meeting". However, with the current code, it plays the second song instead if the first one even though the event is set correctly.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{   
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    // Load data for the ViewModel Items
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }        

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        Appointments appts = new Appointments();

        //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
        appts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<AppointmentsSearchEventArgs>(Appointments_SearchCompleted);

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        int max = 1;

        //Start the asynchronous search.
        appts.SearchAsync(start, end, max, "Appointments Test #1");
        textBlock3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
    }

    void Appointments_SearchCompleted(object sender, AppointmentsSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            AppointmentResultsDataLINQ.DataContext =
                from Appointment appt in e.Results
                where appt.IsAllDayEvent == false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                select appt;       

        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if ((AppointmentResultsDataLINQ.DataContext).Equals("Meeting"))
        {
             mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("http://www.opendrive.com/files/NV8zNTMwNDYwX2hxRXZR/Crystallize.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);              
        }          

        else
        {
            mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("https://www.opendrive.com/files/NV8zMjAxODY0X0VBNDJY/Hetken%20tie%20on%20kevyt%20(piano%20cover)%20-%20YouTube.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);                
        }
            mediaElement1.Play();
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be this line:

```
if ((AppointmentResultsDataLINQ.DataContext).Equals("Meeting"))
```

You're comparing the result of calling the `ToString()` method on the `Appointment` instance with the string "Meeting".

You probably want:

```
if ((AppointmentResultsDataLINQ.DataContext as Appointment).Subject.Equals("Meeting"))
```

**Update**
You're actually checking an Enumerable of Appointments.
Here's how to check if any of them are "Meeting":

```
if ((AppointmentResultsDataLINQ.DataContext as IEnumerable<Appointment>).Any(app => app.Subject.Equals("Meeting")))
```

Comment: I tried your method but it didn't work. When I started the player on the phone, the entire program just quit without displaying any error message.

Comment: @user1876574 without knowing what `AppointmentResultsDataLINQ` is it's going to be hard to provide further assistance. Please provide a complete, minimal, reproduction of the issue so we can help further.